# Understanding TimeUnit

Tags: java, timeunit

I took a look into `TimeUnit` and `toMillis()` method.

```
 public long toMillis(long paramLong)
 {
    throw new AbstractMethodError();
 }
```

`toMillis()` method do nothing other than throw an `AbstractMethodError` exception.

So, How does `toMillis()` method convert seconds, minutes, etc to milliseconds?

Comment: TimeUnit is basically the abstract prototype. You need to look into concrete `TimeUnits`, such as `TimeUnit.SECONDS`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the TimeUnit and look the constants inside...

```
/**
 * Time unit representing one thousandth of a microsecond
 */
NANOSECONDS {
    public long toNanos(long d)   { return d; }
    public long toMicros(long d)  { return d/(C1/C0); }
    public long toMillis(long d)  { return d/(C2/C0); }
    public long toSeconds(long d) { return d/(C3/C0); }
    public long toMinutes(long d) { return d/(C4/C0); }
    public long toHours(long d)   { return d/(C5/C0); }
    public long toDays(long d)    { return d/(C6/C0); }
    public long convert(long d, TimeUnit u) { return u.toNanos(d); }
    int excessNanos(long d, long m) { return (int)(d - (m*C2)); }
},

/**
 * Time unit representing one thousandth of a millisecond
 */
MICROSECONDS {
    public long toNanos(long d)   { return x(d, C1/C0, MAX/(C1/C0)); }
    public long toMicros(long d)  { return d; }
    public long toMillis(long d)  { return d/(C2/C1); }
    public long toSeconds(long d) { return d/(C3/C1); }
    public long toMinutes(long d) { return d/(C4/C1); }
    public long toHours(long d)   { return d/(C5/C1); }
    public long toDays(long d)    { return d/(C6/C1); }
    public long convert(long d, TimeUnit u) { return u.toMicros(d); }
    int excessNanos(long d, long m) { return (int)((d*C1) - (m*C2)); }
},
```

as you will see, every constant in the enumerator TimeUnit 
**NANOSECONDS, MICROSECONDS** etc implements anonymously methods that give you indirect access to `toMillis()` therefore this method

```
 public long toMillis(long duration) {
        throw new AbstractMethodError();
    }
```

is never accessed by your code directly...

Comment: I saw the override methods in JDK but when I used decompiler to decompile 'TimeUnit' from JRE. The override methods are not there. Why does it happens?

Answer (score 7):

Each value within `TimeUnit` overrides it, basically. You never end up calling that implementation, because you never have a reference to an object of type `TimeUnit` - it's always a subclass representing one of the values.

Answer (score 2):

It's method override.

You can see the overrided implementations in NANOSECONDS, MICROSECONDS and etc.